# pgfplots: sequence of linear interpolations between two extremal curves

Tags: pgfplots

Consider two text files, file1.txt and file2.txt, with two columns each, and the same number of rows. Using `pgfplots`, plotting these two files independently would be achieved as follows:

```
\addplot [red] file {file1.txt};
\addplot [blue] file {file2.txt};
```

I would like to also plot all linear combinations of the above curves, linear combinations defined as follows:

```
\foreach \lambda in {0,0.2,...,1} {
    plot \lambda*file1.tex + (1-\lambda)*file2.txt; %<- Mathematical definition to be translated in pgfplots.
}
```

Is there an easy solution to the above problem?

MWE as a starting point:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{file1.txt}
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file2.txt}
0   1
1   2
2.5   0
3   0
4.4   -1
5   1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[red,thick] file {file1.txt};
    \addplot[blue,thick] file {file2.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Having >15k reputation you should know better. Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem. Then I consider thinking about a solution. Without that I (i) have to guess to much and (ii) have to think of dummy data myself.

Comment: @StefanPinnow (1) I was hoping for an existing solution online with a link I would have missed. (2) MWE added as a starting point. (3) I used to have a much lower reputation but it suddenly jumped one day, I do not know why. Thanks!

Comment: Is the fact that your x-values do not match intentional? I imagine that if you want to find linear combinations of the y-values that is possible. But I think for a proper numeric solution, the x-values should either be the same or you'd have to use fit functions/intrapolated values.

Comment: @MarkusG. yes, intentional. We can use the lambda interpolation for the x values as well.